# Getting range for progress bar from two nested for loops

Tags: c++

I have a progress bar to which I need to assign range, and that range needs to be calculated from following nested for loops, is it actually possible to calculate total number of steps required?

```
for (int i = 0; i < i_end; ++i)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < j_end; ++j)
   {
      for (int a = 0; a < a_end; ++a)
      {
      }
      for (int b = 0; b < b_end; ++b)
      {
      }
      ...
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you really ask for `i_end * j_end * (a_end + b_end)`?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if `i_end`, `j_end`, `a_end`, and `b_end` have known max values. As your code stands, all four could potentially be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, leading to an end result of `19,807,040,600,895,968,300,706,562,046`.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando And don't forget to update the progress bar from each of the innermost loops.

Comment: @A.Wabbi and what if those types are signed that is, a_end can be 0 because a is -9000; Suddenly the problem isn't that simple is it?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando you set `a` to 0 in the `for`s; how should it become -9000?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Use [`std::abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)? Really the problem is trivial.

Comment: @user2475059 I set a_end to 0, read what it is written.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are trivial. If I use abs on 'a' it will already be larger than a_end which is equal to '0' and the loop will not loop.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando You didn't address my question. There is nothing besides `int a = 0` that you have given us. It sounds like you're setting `a= -9000` somewhere else, but this has not been shown, so I can't know that behavior.

Comment: @user2475059 and later on I provided another scenario where a == -9000 to prove my point that this isn't trivial.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Then you need to edit the question (or ask a new one) so we can address the specific scenario you have in mind. As it stands, the way you're wording it is pretty confusing, and there isn't any code to clarify the behavior you mean to ask about.

Comment: @thereisnothingwecando Regardless of any assumptions about initial and final values of each loop, the number of iterations is: final_value minus initial_value. The answer of your question is: number_of_iterations_of_i * number_of_iterations_of_j * (number_of_iterations_of_a + number_of_iterations_of_b), supposing no short circuits (break or continue).

Answer (score 2):

If to loops are nested, you need to multiply the number of their respective iterations to get the total number. If the loops are after each other, the total number of iterations is going to be the sum of the respective iterations.

In this case, you end up with

```
i_end * (j_end * (a_end + b_end))
```

since the loop with `j_end` iterations is nested in `i_end`, and the loops with `a_end` and `b_end` are on the same level and nested in `j_end`.

Note that this only holds if none of the loops either break any range stepping (e.g. `i++` somewhere) or short-cuts a iteration with `continue` or `break`.